# Android Compare Two Array?

Tags: java

I have one problem, I need to compare two arrays and I want to get unmatched values.

Example:

```
List<String> Array1=new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> Array2=new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> Array3=new ArrayList<String>();

Array1.add("1");
Array1.add("23");
Array1.add("1211");
Array1.add("12232");
Array1.add("231");
Array1.add("2231");

Array2.add("1");
Array2.add("23");
Array2.add("231");
Array2.add("2231");

// Array3 values are 1211 12232
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please read about [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) which states the Classes begin with an upper-case letter and variables do not.

Comment: FYI this has nothing to do with Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

```
List<String> array3 = new ArrayList<String>(array1);//Create copy of array 1
array3.removeAll(array2);//Remove common elements
```

Answer (score 3):

use Set ( It will remove duplicates too )

```
 Set<String> set1 = new HashSet(array1);
 Set<String> set2 = new HashSet(array2);
 set1.removeAll(set2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it yourself, but it's not terribly hard.  One possible solution:

```
Collections.sort( Array2 );  // Don't need this one if Array2 is already sorted.
for( String s : Array1 ) {
    if ( Collections.binarySearch( Array2, s ) < 0 )
        Array3.add( s );
}
```